# How to declare that a function is arbitrary then specify them later?

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style, functional

I need to evaluate an expression, sum in this case, involving an arbitrary function. Below is a simplified version of what I wanted to do:

```
points = {1.3, 2.4};
f1[g_] = g^2 + 1;
f2[g_] = Sum[f1[g[points[[i]]]], {i, 2}];
```

I want to be general so g is an arbitrary function. It works for simple functions, for example, if I want g[x]=Sin[x], then

```
f2[Sin]
```

gives the correct answer 3.38469. My problem is, in the actual code, g is much more complicated. A simpler example will suffice. If I want g[x]=Sin[x]+Cos[x], then the following does not work:

```
f2[Sin +Cos]
```

Will be glad if someone can help or give a useful hint. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a [pure function definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) for `g`, using `Function` or `&`. For instance, try `f2[Sin[#] + Cos[#]&]`.

Comment: Almost exactly the same question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230934/7936

Answer (score 4):

First recommendation: use `:=` to define your functions.

```
f1[g_] := g^2 + 1
f2[g_] := Sum[f1[g[points[[i]]]], {i, 2}]
```

This guarantees that `g` will be interpreted as the name of the argument pattern, rather than first evaluated as a global symbol.

Now, note that `Sin+Cos` isn't a function, it's just the sum of the symbols `Sin` and `Cos`, usually meaningless. Define a function:

```
h[x_] := Sin[x] + Cos[x]
```

Now, it's all fine:

```
f2[h]
(* 3.51934 *)
```

But now, a further recommendation: don't use `Sum` to add things. `Sum` is a tool of *analysis*, a way to figure out things like infinite sums. Better, and easier, to use `Total`:

```
f3[g_] := Total[f1[g /@ points]]
f3[h]
(* 3.51934 *)
```

Here, I map `g` to the points (`/@`), and take advantage of the fact that your `f1` is implicitly `Listable` to further simplify. An advantage of `Total` here is that it just adds all your points, regardless of how many there are. You need not keep track. Another advantage, when you have many points, is that it's less subject to roundoff error than simply adding the points in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1[x_] := x^2 + 1;
```

Using [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) ( `@*` ) and restricting the argument of `f2` to expressions with the [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and operating on a vector of variable length (length 2 in your example),

```
f2[g_Function] := Total[f1@*g /@ points]

Format[pt[n_]] := Subscript[pt, n]

n = 5;

points = Array[pt, n];

f2[g[#] &]
```

[image]

```
f2[Sin[#] &]
```

[image]

```
f2[Sin[#] + Cos[#] &] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Dear all, thank you so much! These are very helpful comments. As pointed out by evanb, this is a similar question to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230934/how-do-i-define-functionals-in-mathematica So this question might be deleted.  Thank you!